# AccessDeniedException while executing S3NativeFileSystem.mkdir

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I am running a hadoop job on AWS EMR. The job fails with this call stack:

```
Job setup failed : com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: F732367C69BCEEE0), S3 Extended Request ID: 46bzoHyEim9YSGPt/M9F+OupUo3kuV6BJPdqW9AXkhNR+eLh5443kikWSjCZhzLmpBrgf3XeNus=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1160)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:748)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:467)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:302)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1472)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.storeEmptyFile(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:185)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.storeEmptyFile(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.mkdir(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1148)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.mkdirs(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1130)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1865)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.mkdirs(EmrFileSystem.java:402)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.DirectFileOutputCommitter.setupJob(DirectFileOutputCommitter.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:132)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter.setupJob(DirectFileOutputCommitter.java:30)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.setupJob(OutputCommitter.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobSetup(CommitterEventHandler.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

this is not very helpful as i don't know what request it was trying to make to S3. I just see a `S3NativeFileSystem.mkdir` in the call stack. How can I get the arguments to the method? What directory was it trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the output of the job was trying to write to S3 and therefore make the output directory.

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:291)

Does the role have S3 put permissions to the bucket?